# focus on row in extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, focus, refresh, row

thanks to the help of some of you i have this:

```
Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    selectedRecords: [],
    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.getStore().on('beforeload', this.rememberSelection, this);
        this.getView().on('refresh', this.refreshSelection, this);
    },
    rememberSelection: function (selModel, selectedRecords) {
        this.selectedRecords = this.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    },
    refreshSelection: function () {
        if (0 >= this.selectedRecords.length) {
            return;
        }
        var newRecordsToSelect = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
            record = this.getStore().getById(this.selectedRecords[i].getId());
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
                newRecordsToSelect.push(record);
            }
        }
        this.getSelectionModel().select(newRecordsToSelect);
    }
});

var grid = Ext.create('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {

    //autoscroll: true,
    region: 'center',
    autoHeight: true,
    store:  ND.commList,
    stateful: true,
    loadMask: false,
    multiSelect: true,
    //forceFit: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true        
    },
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Vehicle',
            width: 60,
            flex: 0,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'designationId'
        },
        // more code
    ]
    // more code
});
```

When a row is selected it stays selected after a refresh. Now is the list long and you can scroll around in the list. After refresh the correct row is selected only i still need to scroll to that record. How can i focus on that row after a refresh?

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.focusRow()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-focusRow). Something like this in your refreshSelection method:

```
refreshSelection: function () {
    if (0 >= this.selectedRecords.length) {
        return;
    }
    var newRecordsToSelect = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
        record = this.getStore().getById(this.selectedRecords[i].getId());
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
            newRecordsToSelect.push(record);
        }
    }
    this.getSelectionModel().select(newRecordsToSelect);
    this.getView().focusRow(newRecordsToSelect[0]);
}
```

Comment: focusRow needs a row number, newRecordsToSelect[0] contains the record so this exact snippet may not work

Comment: `focusRow()` also accepts Ext.data.Model objects not just numbers, [here it is in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-focusRow). newRecordsToSelect[0] happens to be an `Ext.data.Model` object.

Comment: you are right (+1). i was referring to 3.4.x docs where it does not

Comment: thanks  for  this.getView().focusRow(newRecordsToSelect[0]);
I was looking for it!

Answer (score 1):

You obviously wont be able to scroll multiple records in view if they all dont fit in the view, but lets say you want to scroll a particular selected record (first selected/last selected) into view.

Lets say you look at your newRecordsToSelect and pick one record id that you want to auto scroll to. Lets call this id *`'id of selected record to scroll to'`*

You need [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-scrollIntoView).
i.e. In refresh selection, after you select, do this -

```
var idx = this.getStore().indexOfId('id of selected record to scroll to');
var rowEl = this.getView().getRow(idx);
rowEl.scrollIntoView(this.getGridEl(), false);
```

Comment: Are you saying `focusRow` doesn't do what it is supposed to be doing? I just posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335335/after-loading-store-select-and-show-specific-row-in-grid-works-in-chrome-not-i) in which `focusRow` doesn't seem to work in IE and FireFox (but it _does_ work in Chrome). I'll try tomorrow if `scrollIntoView` works better in my situation.