# After loading store, select and show specific row in grid works in Chrome, not in IE

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I suppose I must be doing something wrong here. I have a GridPanel which gets its data from a Store. The store has a listener on the `load` event, which selects row 8 of the grid's selection model and tries to bring it into focus.

In Chrome (currently version 33) this works and the specified record is visible.
In IE (version 11) this does not work. At the time of the `alert('pause');` statement, the grid is visible with the specified row visible. But after clicking away the alert message, the grid seems to be doing something, cause after that it just show the first few rows.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    // create the data store
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoDestroy: true,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: "/Home/PersonList", method: "POST"}),
        fields: ["First", "Last", "Company", "Email"],
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: function(s, r, o) {
                console.log('store loaded');
                grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(8);
                grid.getView().focusRow(8);
                alert('pause');
            }
        }
    });

    // create the Grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        id: 'grid',
        columns: [{header: 'Company', dataIndex: 'Company'},
            {header: 'First name', dataIndex: 'First'},
            {header: 'Last name', dataIndex: 'Last'},
            {header: 'Email',dataIndex: 'Email'}
        ],
        height: 150,
        listeners: {
            'render': function(component) {
                console.log('grid rendered');
            }
        }
    });

    // render the grid to the specified div in the page
    grid.render(document.body);
});
```

You can't just run this code if you don't have a `/Home/PersonList`-url that returns some Json-data. I don't know if/how I can change the sample to be a complete piece of code (while still having the store autoload the data.

Comment: Have you tried this on some other version of IE? Perhaps try it out by just switching the browser mode in the developer tools?

Comment: Active Scripting enabled?

Comment: @EmilH At work, I've tried my actual code in IE9 and Firefox, with the same result. The sample code I've supplied here I've only tried with IE11 and Chrome 33.

Comment: This question may sound silly, but do you have Development tools enabled on IE? Otherwise the **console.log** calls will cause an error on IE.

Comment: @overlordhammer Yes I do have them enabled.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the **asynchronous nature** of the operations you are performing. There are two operations taking place at the same time here

- **Store load operation**
- **Grid rendering**

Your code attempts to select the 8th row from the grid after the store load event. But **there is not guarantee** that the **grid has been rendered before the store loading operation** have finished since the store has the *autoLoad* configuration value set to true. 
The reason **this code works on Chrome** and not on IE is because **Chrome JavaScript engine is 10 times faster than IE** 9 (IE 10 and 11 engines are also notoriously faster than IE 9) so your UI gets rendered before your loading operation gets finished. However this is just a matter of luck on having the sequence of events being triggered in the right order, to avoid this problem **you should check the current store loading status after the UI has been rendered**, and if it still loading you should deffer the select operation until the store has been loaded, something like:

```
// create the Grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    id: 'grid',
    columns: [{
        header: 'Company',
        dataIndex: 'Company'
    }, {
        header: 'First name',
        dataIndex: 'First'
    }, {
        header: 'Last name',
        dataIndex: 'Last'
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'Email'
    }],
    height: 150,
    listeners: {
        'render': function(component) {
            // Get sure that the store is not loading and that it 
            // has at least a record on it
            if (grid.store.isLoading() || grid.store.getCount() == 0) {
                // If it is still pending attach a listener to load
                // event for a single time to handle the selection
                // after the store has been loaded
                grid.store.on('load', function() {
                    grid.getView().getSelectionModel().select(0);
                    grid.getView().focusRow(0);
                }, this, {
                    single: true
                });
            } else {
                grid.getView().getSelectionModel().select(0);
                grid.getView().focusRow(0);
            }

        }
    }
});
```

You can see a full working example based on your code [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/479). Hope this helps.

Comment: In my situation, it is the load event in which the code determines which record should be selected and focused. I need the loaded data in order to determine the correct row. For instance, in the fiddle, let's say we need to select the row containing Apple.
Also, wouldn't the check for `getCount() == 0` mean that if the store already finished loading, but contains nothing, you attach a `load` handler that will never fire?

Comment: Oops... it seems I was able to modify your fiddle. Didn't know I could do that. Sorry...
I've already got the situation working where I want to select the row containing 'Apple'. Can't get it to work with ExtJS 3.4.0 Classic though (may be a problem with fiddle itself).

Comment: No problem! I was setting up the code with a solution and found the fiddle changed :) Not sure if it will work in the same fashion on 3.4 though, however the main problem here is related to synchronizing the evens and not to the platform itself.

Comment: I suppose my original code was too simplified. We also need to be able to select and focus a specific row after a store reload. I've created a fork of the fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/47g). Here I've tried to use the view's `refresh` event, but the sequence in which events fires seems off. The refresh says the store is already loaded, but the store's load event occurs later.

Comment: [Here's](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/47m) an updated version of your code, you need to handle the load event of the store, not the refresh event of the grid, that way you will get sure that the store has been loaded.

Comment: In Ext JS 3.4, the grid.getView returns an Ext.grid.GridView, which does not have a `getSelectionModel`. The grid itself does have it though. Also, the store doesn't have the `isLoading` method. The RowSelectionModel doesn't have the `select` method, but it does have `selectRow`. With those changes on your code, I still have my original problem in IE11. Unfortunately I'm unable to create a fiddle of it, because the sencha fiddle crashes if you select version 3.4.1 and add mock data ([posted in their forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282680)).

Comment: Try **[this one](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/PLXp6/)**, I've tried on IE 11 and works fine, although it doesn't scrolls all the way down to the row it gets selected as expected (not sure if the scroll issue is just a matter of ExtJs 3.4). Hope this one could help. It uses a jsonp data source if you are having any trouble on loading the data try to modify your IE security settings.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on IE9 here at work. In Chrome (33.0.1750.149 m) it works, but in FireFox (27.0.1) it doesn't scroll the row into view. If you place an `alert` immediately after calling `focusRow`, you see the row focused. But when you click the message away, the grid scrolls back to top. So now you've recreated my original problem. But how can we fix it? I've found that defering the call by 200 ms works, but how solid is that?

Comment: I think that the problem with IE 9 is related to IE blocking jsonp calls due a cross domain security check. I'll try to check the FF issue as soon as I got some spare time.